# will_paginate undefined method 'total_pages' upon ajax request in rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination

**update: what's also interesting is that the ajax does make a request for the next page and I can on my pagination that the next page in the pagination is highlighted, but it doesn't display the content on the next page, it still shows the first page. However, if I click on the second page in pagination the second page of content does show up. It appears that I am getting back my data in JS and not HTML like it does when my app initially loads the data. I tried including a respond_to for HTML in my controller, but that did not solve my issue.

I am using will_paginate to paginate my links in my rails app. I am now trying to implement infinite scroll with will_paginate.

The will_paginate documentation states that you are given the `total_pages` and `next_page` methods on the collection that you paginated.

Given that my pagination is working for links, I am not sure why I am getting a `undefined method total_pages` error in my code.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total_pages' for 3:Fixnum):
    1: $('#link').append('<%= j render(@links) %>');
    2:  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@links.next_page) %>');
  app/views/links/index.js.erb:2:in `_app_views_links_index_js_erb___2850832044435264001_70232955578600'
```

This is my controllers index action:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @links = Link.order(cached_votes_score: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end
end
```

index.js.erb (where the error seems to be occurring):

```
$('#link').append('<%= j render(@links) %>');
 $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@links.next_page) %>');
```

link.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
        $(window).scroll ->
            if $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
                    $.getScript($('.pagination a.next_page').attr('href'))
```

links partial _link.html.erb:

```
<!-- order links based on total number of votes -->
<% @links.each do |link| %>
  <div class="link row clearfix">
    <h2>
      <%= image_tag link.avatar_url(:thumb).to_s %>
    </h2>
    <h2>
      <%= link_to link.title, link %><br>
    </h2>
    <p>
      <%= link_to link.url, link %><br>
    </p>

<!-- acts_as_votable for like_link -->
    <div class="btn-group">
        <%= link_to like_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
          Upvote
          <%= link.get_upvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to dislike_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
          Downvote
          <%= link.get_downvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% unless @links.empty? %>
  <%= will_paginate @links %>
<% end %>
```

If you can lend any insights that would be greatly appreciated, or if you have a question(s) about the code of project, maybe that will trigger something for me that I haven't thought of or I can help you help me.

I have looked through the other answers to similar questions to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from here:

```
j will_paginate(@links.next_page)
```

`@links.next_page is an integer`

Comment: when I can that to just `@links`, it generates a request for all 5 paginated pages as opposed to just the next page. Can you see why it is doing that? Or is removing the `next_page` method not the answer?